# testing over an iterator, how to do it?

Tags: python

I have made a simple generator in Python, it is under a file called program.py

```
class Loop():
    def __init__(self):
        self.i=1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.i>10:
            raise StopIteration
        self.i=self.i+1
        return self.i
```

I have made a unittest module so that it tests the iterator and when there is a number 5 on the list then it prints that the test has failed in that part. I have do something like this:

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
def test(self):
    for x in Loop():
        if not self.assertRaises(AssertionError,self.assertEqual(x,5)):
            print x
```

but I see that this breaks up after the first iteration, what am I doing wrong?

any help?
Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure whatever you are trying to accomplish you are going about it the wrong way.  What exactly are you looking to do?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://pythontesting.net/framework/nose/nose-introduction/. You need to run it *with* the command, which I suspect you're not.

Comment: @user2097159 He's trying to get output using nose, which is a testing module.

Comment: Oh, it also may be because your `if __name__...` line is on the wrong indent, if that is the actual indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching the test incorrectly.

Your iterator is basically the equivalent of `xrange` hardcoded to start from 2 and goes to infinity.

The reason it starts from `2` is because you're initialising `i` to 1 and incrementing `i` inside the next before returning the first value.

I would write the test as follows

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_loop_is_sliceable(self):
        slc = itertools.islice(Loop(), 5)
        self.assertEqual(range(2, 7), list(slc))
```

Also note that asserts are not predicates so they don't give you back a bool to use in conditional statements.